# awk - add values from field based on another field

Tags: bash, awk

The question is incomplete because I couldn't find a good way of expressing it succintly. I have this data:

```
Location   Group   Device#
--------------------------
location1  group01  10
location2  group10   8
location2  groupxx   7
location3  groupAA  11
```

Desired output:

```
Location   Group   Device#   Total_Device#
------------------------------------------
location1  group01  10       10
location2  group10   8       15
location2  groupxx   7       15
location3  groupAA  11       11
```

I've read some solutions on how to sum based on each unique `Location` but I want to keep the results to show as "duplicate" because one location can have 2 or more groups and I want to show each group as well.

Comment: Are you asking for a purely `awk` solution or something else (`bash`, `sqlite`, ...) would be acceptable too?

Comment: Let's say `bash` would be interesting as well but I have doubts it could be done in an equally elegant manner as your `awk` answer below :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming tab-separated columns.

File **tot.awk**:

```
BEGIN{
   # set output separator
   OFS="\t"
}
NR==1{
   # print extended header
   print $0, "Total_Device#"
}
NR==2{
   # print header separator
   print
}
NR>2{
   # store original data in array
   loc[NR]=$1;
   grp[NR]=$2;
   cnt[NR]=$3;
   # store totals in associative array by location
   tot[$1]+=$3
}
END{
   # print each original line with calculated totals
   for (i=3; i<=NR; i++){
      print loc[i], grp[i], cnt[i], tot[loc[i]]
   }
}
```

Output:

```
> awk -f tot.awk data.txt
Location        Group   Device# Total_Device#
--------------------------
location1       group01 10      10
location2       group10 8       15
location2       groupxx 7       15
location3       groupAA 11      11
```

Comment: This is quite an elegant way of using arrays and keeps a high degree of flexibility for further manipulating data and the printed results. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

**Input**

```
$ cat infile
Location   Group   Device#
--------------------------
location1  group01  10
location2  group10   8
location2  groupxx   7
location3  groupAA  11
```

**Output By reading file**

```
$ awk  'NR==1{print $0,"Total_Device#"}NR==2{print $0"--"}NR>2{a[$1]+=$NF; b[i++] = $0}END{for(i in b){split(b[i],d);print b[i],a[d[1]]}}' infile
Location   Group   Device# Total_Device#
----------------------------
location1  group01  10 10
location2  group10   8 15
location2  groupxx   7 15
location3  groupAA  11 11
```

**Explanation**

```
awk  '                                        # call awk
      NR==1{                                  # when awk reads first record
           print $0,"Total_Device#"           # print current record/row with extra field
      }
      NR==2{                                  # when awk reads second record
           print $0"--"                       # print current record with extra string
      }
      NR>2{                                   # if no of records greater than 2 
            a[$1]+=$NF;                       # sum up last field based on location where array is a
            b[i++] = $0                       # save row in array b 
      }
      END{
            for(i in b){                      # loop through array b
                 split(b[i],d);               # split array value where separator being field separator
                 print b[i],a[d[1]]           # print row and location sum
            }
      }' infile
```

**Output By reading same file twice**

```
$ awk  'FNR==NR{if(NR>2){loc[$1]+=$NF};next}FNR==1{print $0,"Total_Device#";next}{print $0,loc[$1]}' infile infile
Location   Group   Device# Total_Device#
-------------------------- 
location1  group01  10 10
location2  group10   8 15
location2  groupxx   7 15
location3  groupAA  11 11
```

**Explanation**

```
awk  '                                        # call awk
      FNR==NR{                                # this is true when awk reads first file
              if(NR>2){                       # if no of records is greater than 2
                 loc[$1]+=$NF                 # sum up last field based on 1st field
              }
              next                            # go to next record, because of this keyword rest of the code will be skipped
      } 
                                              # here we read same file second time
      FNR==1{                                 # if no of records corresponding to current file is equal to one
              print $0,"Total_Device#";       # print current record/row and extra field
              next                            # go to next line
      }
      { 
              print $0,loc[$1];               # print current record and sum which is available in array loc

      }
   ' infile infile
```

Comment: Your solution works too, I gave an upvote but marked Blaf's solution as accepted answer because I consider it more elegant and flexible for further processing. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

One posibility:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{if(/^location/){a[$1]+=$NF}next}{print $0, a[$1]}' your_file your_file
```

**Result**

```
Location   Group   Device# 
-------------------------- 
location1  group01  10 10
location2  group10   8 15
location2  groupxx   7 15
location3  groupAA  11 11
```

**PD**: I will left for you the heading fix.